# Android Volley JsonRequest

Tags: android, json, http-post, android-volley, androidhttpclient

I want to `POST` `JsonObject` from device to server using `Volley` but I couldn't find any code example. If you can please provide me with some references or some code example.

Answer (score 4):

I do it this way

```
public void doRequest(RequestQueue volleyRequestQueue,
        onResponse responseListener) {

    this._responseListener = responseListener;

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            Settings.QUESTIONURL, this, this) {

        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=" + getParamsEncoding();
        }

        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            try {
                return new GsonBuilder()
                        .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create()
                        .toJson(YOUROBJECT).toString()
                        .getBytes(getParamsEncoding());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    };

    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, MAXRETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    volleyRequestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a good reference, where are some good examples :

[Link](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/)